# Azure SQL DB at Idle Shows 12% DTU

Tags: azure, sql

I have instances of an application running where the base program is identical and data volume is similar.  Yet on some instances the idle value shows 12% DTU.  Am I wrong to assume the DTU values at idle should be near 0%?  If so, what should I check to see what is eating up DTUs?

I have taken measurements over numerous weekends when nobody is using the system and I consistently see 12% DTU on idle.

Answer (score 0):

A DTU is a unit of measure for the performance of a service tier and is based on
several characteristics. Each service tier has a certain number of DTUs assigned
to it as an easy way to compare the performance level of one tier versus another.

> [**Database Throughput Unit (DTU):**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-purchase-models#dtu-based-purchasing-model) DTUs provide a way to
>   describe the relative capacity of a performance level of Basic,
>   Standard, and Premium databases. DTUs are based on a blended measure
>   of CPU, memory, reads, and writes. As DTUs increase, the power offered
>   by the performance level increases. For example, a performance level
>   with 5 DTUs has five times more power than a performance level with 1
>   DTU. A maximum DTU quota applies to each server.

The DTU Quota applies to the server, not the individual databases. The DTU% is the percentage of units your particular database is using.
This percentage number is designed to help you choose service tier that is the
most appropriate for your needs.

From toward the bottom of [this announcement](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/11/azure-sql-database-introduces-new-near-real-time-performance-metrics/):

> For example, if your DTU consumption shows a value of 80%, it
>   indicates it is consuming DTU at the rate of 80% of the limit an S2
>   database would have. If you see values greater than 100% in this view
>   it means that you need a performance tier larger than S2.

Conclusion: The meaning of DTU 12% is that you are consuming only 12% of the
resources available to your chosen tier. This number should not increase
while the computer is truly idle. It might indicate that you could use
a lower and less-costly tier, as you are not fully using the allocated resources.

For more information see
[Service tiers in the DTU-based purchase model](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-service-tiers-dtu).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The challenge is that it seems odd resources are being consumed in an idle state.  Recent performance has actually decreased on the sites and reducing to a lower tier further degrades the user experience.  I'm puzzled.  It is like an anchor has been attached to the DB.

Comment: Does the percent increase while the system is idle? If so, you might have some small processes running for maintenance or else.